# Is there a difference between app.use("/", express.static) and app.use(express.static)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a difference between the following, assuming that we first have called `app.set('thePath', thePath)`?

1. `app.use('/', express.static(thePath))`
2. `app.use(express.static(thePath))`
3. `app.use(express.static(app.get('thePath')))`

It seems like (1) and (2) would do the same thing.

As far as I know, in Javascript, if you call a function it evaluates at that time being called, so even if `app.get('thePath')` changes or if `thePath` changes, all of them would stay the same.

If there is a difference, please let me know what and why it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

> If path is not specified, it defaults to “/”.

So yes, 1 & 2 are the same. Assuming `thePath` is a variable pointing to a valid root directory of static assets.

Comment: I saw that but what about subdirectories? Are you sure they do not behave differently wrt subdirectories/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Static files can be requested rom `/`(the root directory) of your node server. The files will be served from the directory that `thePath` points to.

Comment: `var thePath = 'public';`

Then if you request `'/profile.png'` it will come from `/public/profile.png`

Comment: what if I request `/a/b/x.png`?

Comment: `/public/a/b/x.png` ASSUMING `thePath = 'public'`

You often see something along the lines of `app.use('/public', express.static('public'))` and then put all assets in a `public` folder. So in a page you would have `<img src="/public/header.jpg" />`.

Comment: @adam-beck Does using `app.use(express.static(thePath))` call the middleware for every request, even if it wasn't a request for a static resource?

Comment: @edddd yes. It will run for every request